# Recycle Bin manager for Windows 10

Tags: gratis, file-management, windows-10

### 1. Summary

In old times, when I use Windows XP, I use [**RecycleBinEx**](https://www.fcleaner.com/recyclebinex) — extends and enhances for Windows Recycle bin. But in Windows 10 this program not worked correctly. For example, I can not saw names of my files:

[image: Recycle bin]

Program now not supported, [**last post of official blog date 2010 year**](http://blog.fcleaner.com/). I can not find similar program, support Windows 10.

---

### 2. Expected behavior

#### 1. Requirements

1. Gratis,
2. Manage all my recycle bins together,
3. Showing list of deleted time for files.

[image: Deleted time]

#### 2. Desirable requirements

Support most [**RecycleBinEx functions**](https://www.fcleaner.com/recyclebinex).